How can I edit the ckeditor WYSIWYG container by adding classes?
I'm trying to add some css classes to the main ckeditor WYSYWIG container to get it to appear like the textarea element that it's hiding but I can't seem to figure out where i can apply the classes.
to be clear what i want is to add a custom class to the template being used:
<div class="ck ck-reset ck-editor ck-rounded-corners my-custom-class" >

I'm using ckeditor5 in drupal 10.

Do you mind my asking - why? If you already have classes to target, what benefit will another class give you?
